# Phonegap keyboard background black [iOS]

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

I am currently working on a Phonegap app but have a problem when using the basic iOS keyboard. Every time I open the keyboard by focusing a html input field, the keyboard shows up and the view scrolls down so that the input is right above the keyboard.

When I now close the keyboard, a black spot is visible behind the keyboard.
I think it is because when opening the keyboard, the view scrolls over the html body and therefore the body background color but I have absolutely no idea on how to fix this.

The problem is visible in this video: https://cloudup.com/iyzANrxQ5Vg

Is there any way to set the Phonegap app background color without having to go into Objective-C code?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @RenéMorales No. The error still exists.